# Swift: Unable To Set Description on Subclass of NSObject

Tags: swift

I have built a custom class that looks something like this:

```
import UIKit

class Device: NSObject {

    var id = String()
    var name = String()
    var type = String()
    //var description = String()  //Cannot override with a stored property 'description'

}
```

Very simple class, and I am inheriting NSObject so I can use "setValue(value, forKey: keyName)".  However, when I do the following:

```
device.setValue("My Description", forKey: "description")
```

I am getting the following error:

> 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key description.'

So insummary, I can't override the NSObject.description, but when I try to set it I am getting an error.  Anyone run into this before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at where `description` is defined. It is listed in the `NSObjectProtocol` as

```
public var description: String { get }
```

You can only `get` the description property, you can't `set` it.

In Objective-C, description is implemented in most classes as a method; it has no underlined storage. The swift equivalent would be a computed property:

```
public override var description: String {
    return "I'm an object"
}
```

#### tl;dr Use a computed property instead of a stored property

```
class CustomObject : NSObject {
    private var des: String
    override var description: String {
        get {
            return des
        }
        set(newValue) {
            des = newValue
        }
    }

    init(string: String) {
        des = string
    }
}
```

Comment: So if I want to build a custom object as a subclass of NSObject it can never have a description?  That's annoying.

Comment: What is a computed property?

Comment: Yes you can. Computed properties are different because they aren't stored. They are calculated/created/computed whenever they are needed. See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH14-ID259

Comment: My problem is that I am populating a class object based on the values parsed from an XML file.  I don't see how I can use computed properties for this.  I use a loop that populates each property using the setValue function.

Comment: Create a private stored property with a different name than `description` (updated my answer with that)

Answer (score 1):

You can only get the `description` property, you can't `set` it.

In Objective-C string classes, the class `description` for `NSMutableString` specifies that the class inherits from `NSString`. description, when you try to set description it will be getting an error.

> **Method 1**

While using `setValue(value, forKey: keyName)` Use can store property value by using.

```
class ObjName: NSObject{
    var id: String?
    var descriptions : String?

    override var description: String {
        get {
            return self.description
        }
        set(newvalue) {
            descriptions = newvalue
        }
    }
}
```

Using above code, method `setValue` for key `description` value store into the `descriptions`. while you get the value you can use `descriptions`. Also, it does not affect on `description` get.

> **Method 2**

Overriding setValue function. like below.

```
class ObjName: NSObject{
    var id: String?
    var descriptions : String?

    override func setValue(_ value: Any?, forKey key: String) {
        if key == "description"{
           if let desc = value as? String{
               self.descriptions = String()
               self.descriptions = desc
            }
        }else{
            super.setValue(value, forKey: key)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should include some explanation with your code. In general, describing how and why certain commands or code solves a problem is more useful to help the OP – and help others to solve similar issues.

Comment: Yeah! Thank you @AnthonyGeoghegan